# Headers not in first row

Tags: excel, mailmerge

I have an excel document where the headers are not in first row. They go from "C22:AP22". I did a little research and found out that if I selected these cells and used ctrl F3 I could name them. I named them "Headers". When I opened a word doc for mailmerge purposes I can attach the excel as the data source and populate the document with the mergefields (all of my excel "Headers" can be used). When I hit the preview button, the page is blank as if there was not data in my excel datasource. There is data though. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though I feel dumb for what I did, I figure I would post the "answer" in case anyone makes the same mistake. So what I did wrong in my case was I thought I only needed to add the header row "C22:AP22" to use for mail merge, when in fact I needed to add the range "C22:AP999" in order for the mail merge to use the data below my header row. I used "AP9999" but your range would be different.